# How do I read a CUDA .cubin binary file in linux?

Tags: linux, cuda

I'm trying to get the number of registers per thread for each of my kernels in my CUDA program. This will help me use the CUDA Occupancy Calculator (http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls) as to determine the highest occupancy of the GPU for my program.

However, I have generated the .cubin file using the -cubin flag but I am unable to read it in vim/othertexteditors, as suggested by NVIDIA (http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=31279). Does anyone know how to get to read it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is to pass `-Xptxas -v` to `nvcc` like so

```
$ nvcc -Xptxas -v foo.cu
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z9my_kernelPfS_f' for 'sm_10'
ptxas info    : Used 2 registers, 20+16 bytes smem
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`cudaFuncGetAttributes`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_0/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__EXECUTION_ge89e3ebfbbdfa352b048c7d19904fc1b.html) API function to obtain the necessary values at runtime.